# Why is the file.exists() check executed after the file.delete() in mockito argument matcher?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, integration-testing

In my code I try to test a file from which the path is given as string to a method like so:

```
TestClass testClass = spy(new TestClass());

@Test
public void test() {
    testClass.someMethod();


    doNothing().when(testClass).someOtherMethod(any(String.class));
    Mockito.verify(testClass, times(1)).someOtherMethod(argThat(this::checkFile));
}

private boolean checkFile(final String filePath) {
    boolean fileLegit = true;

    File file = new File(filePath);
    assertThat(file).exists();

    try {
        // Some testing on the file
    } catch (IOException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        fileLegit = false;
    }

    file.delete(); // <- Trying to delete

    return fileLegit;
}
```

Here I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting file:
  <path\to\file>
to exist
```

When I remove the `file.delete()` everything works fine, but the file does not get deleted (obviously). I need to delete it after testing though, so do you have any clue why this happens and how to fix it?

Here would be the TestClass object, because some people are intrested in it (blindcoded, but you get the idea):

```
public class TestClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
        content.add("test");

        Path path = Paths.get(/* Choose a path */);

        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createFile(path);
        }

        Files.write(path, content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        someOtherMethod(path.toString());
    }

    void someOtherMethod(String filepath) {
        System.out.println(filepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `file.delete()` does not throw the `AssertionError`! So, where exactly is that error thrown?

Comment: The `assertThat( ... ).something()` is a method from the testing framework assertJ. It's basically a nicer way to write tests instead of JUnit methods. It throws an AssertionError, because the assertJ assertion failed. The assert Method does simply call `file.exists()` in the background though.

Comment: That does not explain, why the code works when leaving out the line `file.delete()`?!? Your question is very unclear! Consider making a [mcve].

Comment: `why the code works when leaving out the line file.delete()` is exactly the question dude. Read more carefully. The example given is 1. Minimal → Just the code that is in question, 2. Complete → You can copy this, create a file and test it out, 3. Reproducible → Don't know about other machines, but on mine it doesn't work. Do you want me to set up your local dev environment or what?

Comment: An additional line in the method cannot cause the throwing of an error in a line above that! Additionally, your example is not complete! What is `TestClass`?

Comment: Then tell me what happens, if that is not what happens. Because I click on test and this is exactly what happens. I have added a shortened version of `TestClass` for you. I thought it would be complete without it, because its not the root of the problem, but whatever - here you have it.

Comment: Then you should add the stacktrace and tell us the exact line where the error occurs.

Comment: It is an assertion error. It occurs exactly on the line where the assert is. The stacktrace is in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205091/discussion-between-seelenvirtuose-and-mauricenino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `testClass` is a `spy` on your `TestClass` object, even so your example does not mention this. Note that you should try to restrict your usage of `spies` to legacy code if you can.

Your problem is related to the fact that the `checkFile` method is invoked twice when you run your unit test. You wrote this code based on the assumption that your method is only invoked once, however that is not how `Mockito` works in this case.

You can easily verify that by adding a `breakpoint` or a `System.out` to your method.

To fix this separate the file deletion logic from the matcher. You might want to add a cleanup (`@AfterEach`) method instead.

Comment: You are right, the object is a spy and the method gets called twice (didn't know). Do you know why it gets called twice and if there is a way to turn it off? Right now I have fixed it with a `@After` cleanup method, but I would really like to know if there is a better / cleaner solution for that?

Comment: The cleanest way is to seperate the things. While debugging mockito, I see one call to check whether the `ArgumentMatcher` matches the argument and a second when the verification checks the number of invocations. There is nothing you can do about this (afaik), thats just the way it is implemented.